# How to fix On "An unexpected error occurred" message when I click on Add new theme or plugin?

Tags: plugins, themes

I am using hostgator hosting services. in every install of wordpress I get the below error message.

"An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums."

Any body have ideas that how to fix it ? I searched on many solution and applied that but no one will work for me yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this error by following ways:

1. Check the hosting panel for blocked ports
2. Contact the Hostgator hosting support - They also inform you regarding the same of blocked port.

On Hostgator shared plan, if your server has suspicious/malicious files on your server then they are blocking the ports.

Some of my contacts faced same issue due to malicious files on their website.

Comment: Yes, it was a port blocking issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have seen issues with installing wordpress thru Fantastico on Hostgator.  Try to load Wordpress manually through FTP and see if that helps.  Takes longder, but a cleaner install.

Comment: Hi, I had checked it with new fresh manual installation but problem is still exist.